# Why is a Fresh React App Using WebSockets?

Tags: reactjs

If I run this command with version 6.14.14 of NPX, I get a clean React app that uses WebSockets:

```
npx create-react-app myAppName
```

I can verify this by starting the app up and opening the debugger console for Firefox. When I first open the console, I don't see any error messages; however, as soon as I terminate the React development server, I start getting errors like this:

```
Firefox can't establish a connect to the server at ws://localhost:3000/ws
```

That happens to be the same port that the HTTP is running through (See Picture Below):
[image]

If I deploy this app to a server that's using a reverse proxy, I get similar WebSocket errors, but my React app strangely continues to work.

Why is a brand new React app using Web Sockets?
What are the consequences of running a React app without allowing this default WebSocket communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, this is a connection to the dev server for HMR and should not impact the application runtime (actually it should not be enabled in production build at all using cra and you should be able to verify this quite easily).

Comment: It sounds like my production build isn't deployed correctly then.